# WaitOnAddress doesn't wake after the variable changed

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

According to [WaitOnAddress doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN), `WaitOnAddress` should block until the value at the given address changes.

```cpp
#include <synchapi.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

#pragma comment(lib,"Synchronization.lib")

namespace __monitorVaribleChangeTest
{

    void startAThreadToWaitAVaribleChange(int& a)
    {
        std::thread th([&a]() {
            auto b = a;
            cout << "WaitOnAddress start\n";
            WaitOnAddress(&a, &b, sizeof(a), INFINITE);
            cout << "WaitOnAddress passed\n";
            });
        th.detach();
    }

    void main()
    {
        int a = 100;
        startAThreadToWaitAVaribleChange(a);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3000ms);
        a = 99;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3000ms);
    }
}
```

So, `WaitOnAddress passed` is supposed to be shown after `a = 99;` – but it never showed.

[image]

Comment: of course simply change value at address not enough. need *call WakeByAddressSingle to wake a single waiting thread or WakeByAddressAll to wake all waiting threads.*

Comment: Reading - Old New Thing - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160823-00/?p=94145

Comment: Raymond's blog has quite a few articles on how to use `WaitOnAddress`, including a look at how it is implemented behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation that you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress?redirectedfrom=MSDN), you will need to signal that the value at the given address has changed, by calling either `WakeByAddressSingle` or `WakeByAddressAll`:

> The address on which to wait. If the value at Address differs from the
> value at CompareAddress, the function returns immediately. If the
> values are the same, the function does not return ***until another thread
> in the same process signals that the value at Address has changed by
> calling WakeByAddressSingle or WakeByAddressAll*** or the timeout
> elapses, whichever comes first.

The following version of your `main` does what (I think) you expect:

```cpp
    void main()
    {
        int a = 100;
        startAThreadToWaitAVaribleChange(a);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3000ms);
        a = 99;
        WakeByAddressSingle(&a);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3000ms);
    }
```

Comment: It would awake even the variable doesn't change. That makes the Wait-On-Address seems meaningless.

Comment: @Zhang It seems that the "What-shall-we-call-our-function?" committee had rather too much Hooch in their coffee at that meeting. Maybe `WaitIfSame()` would have been a better name. But, overall, the function *does* give a much simpler synchronization method than using mutexes or other WinAPI-based systems.

Comment: ... but I think the "On-Address" part of the name just refers to the fact that you can have different objects at different addresses to wait on.

Comment: @Zhang You must change the value to guarantee that WaitOnAddress will wake. (There are edge cases where it will not wake because the value hasn't changed.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Interesting. I have edited my answer to reflect what you said. Any chance of an example of such an "edge case"?

Comment: In the above example, if the thread takes more than 3s to start, then it will not wake.